# How do I get an application id for the Paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I've been going around in circles with the paypal documentation. How do I get a paypal app id for the paypal sandbox using the Adaptive Payment API? I already have a username/password/signature for the sandbox.

**Adaptive Payments has been deprecated. Please see the comment from Lenny Markus (current Director of Engineering at PayPal) on the answer below.**

Comment: Can you specify which API operation you trying to execute? Is it the [Invoicing API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_InvoiceAPIExamples)?

Comment: The Adaptive Payment API

Comment: check here [sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/api/?mark=app%20id#adaptive-payments-endpoints)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**Adaptive Payments has been deprecated. Please see the comment from Lenny Markus (current Director of Engineering at PayPal) below.**

If you're testing Adaptive API calls, use the static Sandbox AppID:

- [APP-80W284485P519543T](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/apps-101)

Comment: Thanks. I see that in the demo examples but assumed was dummy data like the other values in examples.

Comment: @SgtPooki you specifically mentioned for 'testing Adaptive API calls'. Do you mean there is a separate Sandbox AppID for calls like GetBasicPersonalData, if so what is it? Or is it that they don't need an APPID?

Comment: @Nilesh, GetBasicPersonalData requires use of the APP-ID as well, see page 22 here: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Permissions.pdf

Comment: wow, the paypal api documentation is so badly written

Comment: Amazing to have to come to SO for this.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/gs_PayPalAPIs/#credentials

Comment: It is referenced in the [permissions service documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/gs_PermissionsService/#make-your-first-call) and I thought it was just an example reading it the first time.

Comment: Hello! PayPal Developer Relations here. For future people landing here: Adaptive Payments has been deprecated. No new applications are being accepted at this time, so you shouldn't integrate this.  Please visit developer.paypal.com for alternatives!

Comment: @LennyMarkus heyo.. thanks for the update. I'll add a marker to the answer.