# Paypal Classic Merchant sandbox account + app

Tags: paypal

In getting https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby to work with Padrino, I need an app id

```
...
app_id: APP-80W284485P519543T
....
```

but within PayPal, I can only find where to create sandbox **accounts** but not **apps**. The only option seems to be an official "new app" request, with details that aren't really that relevant for testing purposes.

[form](http://postimg.org/image/n9ipin721/)

Do I have to submit this info even before beginning to implement functionality in the app I'm developing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App ID you posted above will be the one you will use for sandbox testing. When you are ready to move it to the live environment, have a look at [Going Live with Your Application](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/goingLive/).

Comment: thanks! in the meantime i found this (looked before but missed it) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164332/how-do-i-get-an-application-id-for-the-paypal-sandbox. not deleting the question unless someone suggests doing so. cheers.